# how to gradually increase the speed of object coming to you

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

i'm a beginner and i trying to create a game like subway surfer, where obstacle will come towards player and the player needs to avoid it. the speed of the object will gradually increase over time. so in order to achieve that i decide to use an empty game object as a global speed manager. the speed manager have a variable named speed where all the obstacle spawned on the scene will refer to in order to determine their speed, and somehow it doesn't work. can someone show me why my code does not work ?

here is the speed manager code

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;

 public class Speed : MonoBehaviour {
 public float kelajuan = 10f;
 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () {

 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () 
 {
     kelajuan += Time.deltaTime/40;
 }
 }
```

here is the obstacle code

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class landmove : MonoBehaviour {

 public float sped;


 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () 
 {
     GameObject manager = GameObject.Find ("manager");
     Speed speed = manager.GetComponent<Speed> ();
     speed.kelajuan = sped; 
 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {

     transform.Translate (-sped * Time.deltaTime, 0, 0);


     if (transform.position.x < -10)
     {
         Destroy(gameObject);
     }

 }
}
```

here is the obstacle spawn code. there are 4 different obstacles

```
 using UnityEngine;
 using System.Collections;
 using System.Collections.Generic;
 public class obstaclespawn : MonoBehaviour {
 public List<GameObject> obPrefabs;
 //public GameObject asa;

 // Use this for initialization
 void Start () 
 {
     StartCoroutine(enemySpawn());

 }

 // Update is called once per frame
 void Update () {

 }

 IEnumerator enemySpawn()
 {
     while (true) 
     {
         GameObject asa = obPrefabs[Random.Range(0,obPrefabs.Count)];
         yield return new WaitForSeconds (Random.Range (1,3));
         Instantiate (asa);
     }
 }
```

}

the problem is that whenever a new obstacle is spawned, the global speed reset to zero. so all the obstacle that spawned did not move at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're not making any relation between your obstacle code "landmove" and the spawned obstacles "obstaclespawn", so when you spawn a new "asa" game object it won't find any components attached to it, hence your newly spawned object won't move.
Another issue in your code is this line (speed.kelajuan = sped), you're resetting it to 0 as **sped** is the local variable which is initialized at 0. Change it to (sped = speed.kelajuan) to get the real value of speed.kelajuan.

Hope this helps.